# Razor Page Method RedirectToPage calls action, but does not load the page (No MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redirect, razor, razor-pages

I have a project with a few Razor Pages. The first is a log in where on submit I call this method.

```
        public RedirectToPageResult OnPostLogin()
        {

            string salt; // grab the unique salt we stored on the database
            string hashedPassword;
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("UserDBContext")))
            {
                salt = conn.Query<string>(GetDBSalt(), new // grabs the salt from the database 
                {
                    @Email = Email
                }).FirstOrDefault();

                if (salt != null)
                {
                    hashedPassword = PasswordHash.Hash(Password, Convert.FromBase64String(salt)); // hashes the password and salt to compare against the database password
                }
                else
                {
                    hashedPassword = "";
                }

                var result = conn.Query<Guid>(CheckUserSql(), new
                {
                    @Email = Email, // ditto below 
                    @Password = hashedPassword // checks if the hashed password matches the password we have on the database 
                }).FirstOrDefault();
                var resultString = result.ToString();
                if (resultString != "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
                {
                    //Response.Redirect($"/CardPage/{resultString}");
                    return RedirectToPage("CardPage", "Card",  new { id = resultString });
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("LogIn");
                }
            }
        }
```

Then goes to the cshtml page, CardPage, where this OnGet method is called.

```
        public void OnGetCard(string id)
        {                        
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("UserDBContext")))
            {
                var cards = conn.Query<string>(GetUserSql(), new
                {
                    @Id = id
                }).FirstOrDefault();
                this.HttpContext.Session.SetString("Id", id);
                CardsSelected = cards;
            }            
        }
```

This works perfectly fine, it moves the id to the next page and I'm able to do what I need to on this page. But when I try to do the exact same thing on CardPage with this OnPost method. This OnPost is called from an AJAX method.

```
public RedirectToPageResult OnPost([FromBody] Cards cards)
        {
            var urlId = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Id");
            var cardString = cards.cards;
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("UserDBContext")))
            {
                conn.Execute(SetCardsSql(), new
                {
                    @Cards = cardString,
                    @Id = urlId
                });
            }
            return RedirectToPage("HierarchyPage", "Build", new { id = urlId });           
        }
```

And this OnGet method

```
public void OnGetBuild(string id)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("UserDBContext")))
            {
                var cards = conn.Query<string>(GetUserSql(), new
                {
                    @Id = id
                }).FirstOrDefault();
                this.HttpContext.Session.SetString("Id", id);
                CardsSelected = ParseCardsSelected(cards);
            }
            string slotHTML;
            int slotID = 1;
            // create the rows of the pyramid and insert its slots
            for (int currentRowNumber = 1; currentRowNumber <= MAX_ROWS; currentRowNumber++)
            {
                slotHTML = "";
                for (int n = 1; n <= currentRowNumber; n++, slotID++)
                {
                    // generates slot HTML and assigns an unique ID to each slot
                    slotHTML += string.Format(CARD_SLOT_HTML, slotID);
                }
                Rows += string.Format(SLOT_ROW_HTML, currentRowNumber, slotHTML);
            }
            Rows = new string(Rows.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || c.Equals(' ')).ToArray());            
        }
```

The method is called and executed, then goes to the cshtml page where I have the model set up. All of this executes correctly, but the **page does not load in the browser**. I have been searching for hours on end to find a solution, but I can't find anything with a similar problem. I have a temporary workaround by taking the url that should be loaded and manually loading it and it works that way.

To recap, the first two methods work, the second two methods do not work. In the second sequence, the methods are called in the OnGet, but the page is not loaded into view. When putting the url in manually, the page is loaded into view correctly. Log in --> CardPage works, CardPage --> HierarchyPage does not work.

I will update this question with more code if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Ajax , you should redirect to another page and pass parameter from client side in success callback function :

```
$.ajax({
    ...
}).done(function (data) {
    window.location.replace(data.redirectUrl);

})
```

Server side will return Json result with parameter :

```
public ActionResult OnPost([FromBody]Cards cards)
{

    ...
    return new JsonResult(new { redirectUrl = Url.Page("HierarchyPage", "Build", new { id = urlId }) });
}
```